# Save user-defined object into Windows Registry using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to save created object into Windows Registry and after reopening application to read it? I know how to save and read string but this is complex object.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You maybe want to use a [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) (or other serializers). It's easy to use, and the documentation is full of examples.

But why storing it in the registry?

Better use [Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750).

**EDIT:**

Instead of the registry, save your object to a file in the ApplicationData directory of the user. You can get the path to this directory with

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Full example:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Module Module1

    Public Class MySuperClass
        Public Property MyString() As String
        Public Property MyInt() As Int32
    End Class

    Public Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim myFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyApplication")
        If Not Directory.Exists(myFolder) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolder)
        End If

        Dim myFile = Path.Combine(myFolder, "MySettings.txt")

        Dim o = New MySuperClass With {.MyString = "Hi!", .MyInt = 42}
        Dim x = New XmlSerializer(GetType(MySuperClass))

        Using sr = New StreamWriter(myFile)
            ' Save directly to file
            x.Serialize(sr, o)
        End Using

        ' for demonstrating purpose
        o = Nothing

        Using sr = New StreamReader(myFile)
            ' Load directly from file
            o = CType(x.Deserialize(sr), MySuperClass)
        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Agreed.  Storing complicated objects in the registry is not a good idea.  better to store as a file in the user profile.

Comment: Thanks!I need that object after reopening apllications. Is there another way beside saving in registry?